# mousedown event not always firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript in my page:

```
$("#attach-body").mousedown(function (event) {
//alert(event.button);
switch (event.button) {
    case 2:
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        break;
    default:
}
```

If I uncomment the alert it works fine, but if I don't the event doesn't fire. I'm trying to disable the right click on a modal form("#attach-body"). Does someone know a better way to do it so I don't have to have unnecessary alerts?

Comment: This is impossible. The alert can't prevent the event from firing.

Comment: that's why I came here. I can also get the event to fire if I use developer tools and add a breakpoint. This is in Chrome and IE 11

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `contextmenu` event (shaky support)

```
$(function(){
  $('#dont-click').on('contextmenu', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on('contextmenu', '#attach-body', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Try this one.

1. Always use "on" - it is more flexible than it`s shorthands
2. Disabling right mouse context menus is a bad idea...
3. If you set first target to a document you will get the ability to fire event on an element even if it is generated during page lifespan (even if target element has been generated later via js or ajax)